# how to jarray convert to object array?

Tags: android

i want add like below array please help me this  through loop please help me this; my logic gets last image of array

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

            try {

                String urlimage = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imageurl");
                String name = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagename");

                myarr = new SpacePhoto[]{  new SpacePhoto(urlimage, name),};

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

example i want add array like below

```
  return new SpacePhoto[]{

    //                new SpacePhoto("http://i.imgur.com/zuG2bGQ.jpg", "Galaxy"),
    //                new SpacePhoto("http://i.imgur.com/ovr0NAF.jpg", "Space Shuttle"),
    //                new SpacePhoto("http://i.imgur.com/n6RfJX2.jpg", "Galaxy Orion"),
    //                new SpacePhoto("http://i.imgur.com/qpr5LR2.jpg", "Earth"),
    //                new SpacePhoto("http://i.imgur.com/pSHXfu5.jpg", "Astronaut"),
    //                new SpacePhoto("http://i.imgur.com/3wQcZeY.jpg", "Satellite"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
SpacePhoto[] myarr = new SpacePhoto[jarray.length()]

 for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

            try {

                String urlimage = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imageurl");
                String name = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagename");

                myarr[i] = new SpacePhoto(urlimage, name);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```